# Using annotations in spring boot for putting data in correct format

Tags: spring-boot, annotations

I have a field in my entity that holds phone-number. According to the conventions of the project, I need to save it in E.164 format in the DB. At the moment I use @PrePersist and @PreUpdate annotations for changing the phone number to the specified format. This method is good for one or two entities but it becomes very error-prone when you have to repeat it over and over.

I was thinking that it would be awesome if I could put the code in annotation and the annotation reads the fields and changes its value just before the persistence something like what @LastModifiedDate and annotation do. I searched the web for the codes of this annotation but I didn't understand how they managed it.

How I can write an annotation that reads the value of a field and changes it before persistence, and how I can do it before some specific operations like delete (I want to set some params before deleting the object too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [EntityListeners](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.2/api/javax/persistence/EntityListeners.html).

You can create a listener that checks your custom annotation and triggers the appropriate methods.

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface TheCustomAnnotation{
}
```

```java
@Entity
@EntityListeners(TheListener.class)
public class TheEntity {

    @TheCustomAnnotation
    private String phoneNumber;
```

```java
public class TheListener {

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist(Object target) {
        for(Field field : target.getClass().getDeclaredFields()){
          Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotations();
          // Iterate annotations and check if yours is in it.
        }
    }
```

This is just an example.

Comment: Could you explain more how I can check for target annotations? and how I must implement the annotations, do I need simply define an annotation, or it needs a specific code and ...?

Answer (score 1):

`@Pattern` is a pretty powerful annotation that would be a good fit for validations if you are experienced with regular expressions.

For example,

```
@Pattern(regexp="^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$")
private String phoneNumber;
```

The downside is that this only works for Strings though.

If you are interested more in conversions than validations, you may want to look into `@JsonDeserialize` if you are using Jackson.

For example:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using=PhoneNumberDeserializer.class)
private String phoneNumber;
```

```
Pattern phonePattern = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]{3}(.+)[0-9]{3}(.+)[0-9]{4}$");

public class PhoneNumberDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, 
            DeserializationContext deserializationContext) 
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

        String phone = jsonParser.getText();

        if (matcher.matches(phone)) {

            Matcher matcher = phonePattern.matcher(phone);

            for (int i = 1; i < matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                marcher.group(i).replaceAll(".*", "");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will work for any type, not just strings.

Sorry it's a little convoluted, I was having fun reteaching myself.